# Как создать журналы для материализованного представления для быстрого обновления (fast refresh)?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть материализованное представление (MV), основанное на двух или более других материализованных представлениях.

Планирую сделать быстрое обновление (*fast refresh*) для материализованного представления, но проблема в том, что у него нет журналов, поэтому сначала надо создать журналы. Но не уверен, как создать журналы для двух базовых материализованных представлений.

Необходимо ли создать журнал для каждой базовой таблицы, которые используются базовыми материализованныи представлениями и отдельно для самих этих представлений?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Materialized view logs questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59585716) от участника [@Coding Duchess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1812278/coding-duchess)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/59585716

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы обеспечить быстрое обновление, нужны MV журналы на:

- все базовые таблицы
- все базовые MV лежащие в основе целевого MV.

Другими словами, нужно создать журналы для всех объектов в цепочке зависимостей, кроме корневого MV.

Посмотрим на самом простом примере:

```
create table t1 (c1 int primary key, c2 int)
/
create table t2 (c1 int, c2 int, primary key (c1, c2))
/
create materialized view log on t1
    with rowid, primary key ( c2 ) including new values
/
create materialized view log on t2
    with rowid, primary key including new values
/
create materialized view mv1 refresh fast on commit as
    select * from t1
/
create materialized view mv2 refresh fast on commit as
    select * from t2
/
```

Журналы на MV создаются таким же образом, как и на обычные таблицы:

```
create materialized view log on mv1
    with rowid (c1, c2) including new values
/    
create materialized view log on mv2
    with rowid (c1, c2) including new values
/
create materialized view mv3 refresh fast on commit as
    select mv1.c1, count (*) total
    from mv1 
    join mv2 on mv2.c1 = mv1.c1
    group by mv1.c1;
```

Тестовые данные и результат:

```
insert into t1 values (1, 1);
insert into t1 values (2, 2);

insert into t2 values (1, 1);
insert into t2 values (1, 2);
insert into t2 values (2, 2);

commit;
    
select * from mv3;

        C1   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          1
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59611355) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>